# Change date style backend symfony

Tags: date, symfony1, backend

I generated the backend on my project and the date appears like October 10, 2011. I need it to appear like 10/10/2011. How do I do it?

thank you

Comment: Need to be a little more specific about where... sounds like it's in the index (list) action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the date_format pattern, e.g.

```
     lastseen_at: { label: Last visit, date_format: dd/MM }
```

Comment: thank you. I was trying to use lastseen_at: { params: date_format="dd/MM/" } but didn't worked